# HD Crash SQL server -> DBCC - consistency errors in table 'sysindexes'

Tags: sql-server

Hello A client of mine has had an HD crash an a SQL DB got corrupt :
They did not make backups so they have a big problem.
When I tried (an ultimate measure) to DBCC-repair I got the following message.
Can anybody help me with this ?

```
Server: Msg 8966, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not read and latch page (1:872) with latch type SH. sysindexes failed.
Server: Msg 8944, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 2, index ID 0, page (1:872), row 11. Test (columnOffsets->IsComplex (varColumnNumber) && (ColumnId == COLID_HYDRA_TEXTPTR || ColumnId == COLID_INROW_ROOT || ColumnId == COLID_BACKPTR)) failed. Values are 2 and 5.
        The repair level on the DBCC statement caused this repair to be bypassed.
CHECKTABLE found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table 'sysindexes' (object ID 2).
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Comment: You should address this type of questions on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Paul Randal's blog has a really good article on CHECKDB.

http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle.aspx